# stone stacking game

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm trying to find a game that I played a while ago with some friends, and not having much luck with Amazon/Google.

Each player got a set of stones, and you were supposed to stack the stones in a tower according to the image on a card. I think there were different colored stones that were supposed to be used in different places in the tower.

Does anyone know the name of this, or a similar game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, I own this game!  It's called **Rukshuk**.

Here's a [link](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24028/rukshuk).

Comment: My pleasure - someone gave it me as a birthday present I think once, and it's a fun little game. Definitely a break from the norm where boardgames are concerned!